# SharePoint 2010 Excel Web App

Tags: office-web-apps

I have just completed a in-place upgrade from SharePoint 2007 to 2010 and everything completed successfully.

I have installed the Office WebApps and followed all the steps to enable Word, Excel and PowerPoint.

When I try an open a xlsx file form a Document List it returns this error message:

> This workbook cannot be opened because it is not stored in an Excel
>   Services Application trusted location.
>
> To create an Excel Services Application trusted location, contact
>   your system administrator.

I have checked the Trusted Location settings and the default is for the whole ShaprePoint server.

Opening Word docs work fine with the web version.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read this post?
http://www.sharepointedutech.com/2010/06/22/sharepoint-2010-cannot-open-workbook-because-its-not-stored-in-an-excel-services-application-trusted-location/

Comment: Thanks, the post refers to sites using SSL which we are not using.  

Another other thing is there is no event being logged, which is making it hard to debug.

Comment: Any clues in the ULS logs?

Answer (score 0):

I actually ran into this same error on a new installation (not upgrade).   It also defaulted to the entire server as a trusted location.  What I planned to try tomorrow is to go ahead and explicitly add the library to the trusted locations anyway.  Perhaps you should try the same.